# how do i access the model that is inside (for/loop)?

Tags: flutter, bloc

**> How do i access the model that is inside (for/loop)  ?**

> MyCode :

```
    on<AddCar>((event, emit) {
     for (var i = 0; i < event.cars.length; i++) {
       Car(
         id: 110,
         type: event.cars[i].type,
         color: event.cars[i].color,
       );
     }

     final cars = state.copyWith(
      car: List.from(state.car)..add( // empty ),
     );
     emit(cars);
   });
```

> the result i want  :

```
   on<AddCar>((event, emit) {
   for (var i = 0; i < event.cars.length; i++) {
     final data = Car(
         id: 110,
         type: event.cars[i].type,
         color: event.cars[i].color,
       );
     }

     final cars = state.copyWith(
      car: List.from(state.car)..add( data ),
     );
     emit(cars);
   });
```

**> How do i access the model that is inside (for/loop)  ?**

Comment: so what do you mean by `final data = for (` ?

Comment: i want to access the Car model, and put in add(). how can I access Model Car? @pskink

Answer (score 1):

```
on<AddCar>((event, emit) {
   List<Car> listCars = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < event.cars.length; i++) {
    listCars.add (Car(
         id: 110,
         type: event.cars[i].type,
         color: event.cars[i].color,
       ),);
     }

     final cars = state.copyWith(
      car: List.from(state.car)..addAll(listCars),
     );
     emit(cars);
   });
```

Or

```
on<AddCar>((event, emit) {
   List<Car> listCars = event.cars.map((var car) => Car(
         id: 110,
         type:car.type,
         color: car.color,
       )).toList();

     final cars = state.copyWith(
      car: List.from(state.car)..addAll(listCars),
     );
     emit(cars);
   });
```

Comment: not working, response. The argument type 'List<Car>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Car'

Comment: you want to assign List<Car> to Car. Show me what is your State

Comment: it's the same, it gets the same response @fugipe

Comment: The bug is State.CopyWith(_).
What do you want to do ? 
Do you want to add a car to list of cars ?

Comment: yes i want to add some cars to car list @fugipe

Comment: your error it's  "car: List.from(state.car)..addAll(listCars)" you want to add a list of car to a single car. Like this String s = List.from(listString).addAll(listString2); . You need to change to this List<String> s = List.from(listString).addAll(listString2)

Comment: I don't really understand can you provide a reference? @fugipe

Comment: add your model of your "State" to your post

Comment: List.from(state.car) ? @fugipe